# opencart 1.5.6 fatal error Class 'Config' not found

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I  am getting a temporary error in the opencart page. I have listed all the errors that I am getting. while reloading the page the error disappears and work fine.

The link I am using is 
https://www.buccaneerbaybbq.com/shop/

```
[10-Jun-2014 11:14:30 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Config' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 42
[10-Jun-2014 11:15:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Loader' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 38
[10-Jun-2014 11:16:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Config' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 42
[10-Jun-2014 11:16:57 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 46
[10-Jun-2014 11:19:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Loader' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 38
[10-Jun-2014 11:19:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 46
[10-Jun-2014 11:20:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Loader' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 38
[10-Jun-2014 11:20:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 46
[10-Jun-2014 11:21:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Front' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 227
[10-Jun-2014 11:21:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Config' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 42
[10-Jun-2014 11:21:44 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Language' not found in /home/buccaneerbay/public_html/shop/index.php on line 188
```

anyone please go through and shed some light on this.

Comment: this is a problem i have never  faced before with opencart, although i would suggest that an edit via a vqmod script for example may come up with these results. Do you have default index.php? My hunch point me toward VqMOD.

Comment: Yeah have the default index.php file and using opencart 1.5.6 and installed vqmod is there any way we can sort it out by editing vqmod

Comment: hmm do you have any VqMOD scripts that edit index.php?